# Eigenvalues of Matrix Polynomials and transformations that leave them invariant

Tags: matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, spectral-theory

I am dealing with the following problem.

For $k,d \in \mathbb{N}$ we consider a set of square matrices $A =\{A_0,\ldots,A_{d-1}\} \subset \mathbb{C}^{k \times k}$ and associate with it a matrix polynomial as,
$P_A(\lambda) = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} A_i \lambda^{i}$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. The eigenvalues of $P_A(\lambda)$ are defined as 
$\lambda(A) = \{\lambda : \text{det}(P_A(\lambda)) = 0\}$.

Now, consider the invertible matrix $M = (m_{i,j})_{{i,j} \in \{0,\ldots,d-1\}} \in \mathbb{C}^{d \times d}$, which defines a new set of matrices $B = (B_0,\ldots,B_{d-1})$ via $B_i = \sum_{j=0}^{d-1} m_{i,j} A_{j}$.

I am interested in the following question:

**What is the set of invertible matrices $M$ such that $\lambda(A) = \lambda(B)$?**

Some remarks:

- $d = 1$: the problem is trivival.
- $d = 2$: we can use the theory of matrix pencils to completely solve the problem (see e.g. the classic book of [Gantmacher](https://bookstore.ams.org/chel-133/)).
- $d>2$: A complete solution of the problem appears to be elusive. Can we get strong necessary conditions that $M$ has to fulfill?

Possible approaches for $d>2$:

To a matrix polynomial $P_A(\lambda)$ one can assign a compagnion matrix pencil $\tilde{P}_A(\lambda) = \tilde{A}_0 + \lambda \tilde{A}_1$, where $\tilde{A}_i \in \mathbb{C}^{k' \times k'}$,$k' = (d-1)k$ (see e.g. [here](http://math.bme.hu/~bnagy/ekvivmp.pdf) for the precise definition). The eigenvalues of $P_A(\lambda)$ can then be determined from the eigenvalues of $\tilde{P}_A(\lambda)$. This might give some strong necessary conditions that $M$ has to fulfill.

There are various bound on the modulus of the elements in $\lambda(A)$ (see e.g. 
[Bounds 1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/03081087.2018.1430118?needAccess=true),
[Bounds](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0024379501003160/1-s2.0-S0024379501003160-main.pdf?_tid=4e9f5383-1263-4a46-832d-15f0e95c8bb0&acdnat=1524226605_af56ab2def88f66afd8128c153cab2cf)).
But it is not clear to me how they will be useful.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best